# Graphiz: how to draw crossing edge of a single node

Tags: graphviz, dot, pygraphviz

I want to create nodes in a bigger graph, which have crossing or non crossing inner connections.

Like so:
[image: crossing edge]

But with graphviz, I'm so far not able to produce it.

The following example doesn't work, no matter, if splines=line, overlap=false or spline is given directly to the edge:

```
digraph {
  splines=line
  node [shape=box]
  "myNode"
    "myNode":nw -> "myNode":se [color=red, splines=line]
    "myNode":sw -> "myNode":ne [color=red]
}
```

It just results in the following node:

[image: crossing edge incorrect]

[Here is the link](https://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/?1478860611743#digraph%20%7B%0A%20%20splines%3Dline%0A%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3Dbox%5D%0A%20%20%22myNode%22%0A%09%22myNode%22%3Anw%20-%3E%20%22myNode%22%3Ase%20%5Bcolor%3Dred%2C%20splines%3Dline%5D%0A%09%22myNode%22%3Asw%20-%3E%20%22myNode%22%3Ane%20%5Bcolor%3Dred%5D%0A%7D) to a corresponding graphviz fiddle.